# Capture Upload Image Failed iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, afnetworking-2

I m trying to upload image through AFNetworking.
Following is the way I try to save image in an array. Image uploading starts, but right after the 1.1% of upload it stops uploading without any error. No Idea what is happening.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

 [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);

ImageObject *imageObject=[[ImageObject alloc]init];

imageObject.image=chosenImage;
imageObject.imageData=imageData;
imageObject.imageUploadStatus=FALSE;
imageObject.isUploaded=FALSE;
[imageObject setDescription:@""];

[imageDataArray addObject:imageObject];
}
```

After this I upload image with Following method.

```
-(void)uploadPicturesAndVides:(NSMutableArray *)_list descriptions:(NSMutableArray *)_description categoryID:(NSString *)_catID categoryName:(NSString *)_categoryName index:(NSInteger)_index{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[SettingValues getRSFToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"_csrf"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"USER_Agent_Value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
NSString *imageUrl;
imageUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user/upload/photo",BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS];
NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (ImageObject *object in _list) {
    [tempArray addObject:[object description]];
}
NSString *descriptions;
descriptions=[tempArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"descriptionImage":descriptions,@"subcategoryId":_catID,@"subcategoryName":_categoryName,@"_csrf": [SettingValues getRSFToken]};

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op =    [manager POST:imageUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    NSInteger count=_index;
    for (ImageObject *object in _list) {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG00%zd.png",count];
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:object.imageData name:@"files" fileName:imageName mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [SettingValues setImageUploadStatus:TRUE];
    [self uploadingRequestSuccessfulWithObject:responseObject reqestName:@"picture" index:_index];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
}];
[op setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    double percentDone = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    [self goBackTouploadingControllerWithProgressResult:percentDone index:_index];
}];
cancelManager=op;
[op start];
}
```

Following is the image and its progress stays here! no success no failure. :(
[image]

Problem is that code works when I upload image through Camera Roll, But when I capture image, it did not. 
I put a `NSLog(@"progress updated(percentDone) : %f", percentDone);` in Progress Block and I found the following logs

```
2015-02-07 13:07:22.854 APP_Name[2069:60b] progress updated(percentDone) : 0.002105
2015-02-07 13:07:22.858 APP_Name[2069:60b] progress updated(percentDone) : 0.004210
2015-02-07 13:07:22.860 APP_Name[2069:60b] progress updated(percentDone) : 0.006315
2015-02-07 13:07:22.861 APP_Name[2069:60b] progress updated(percentDone) : 0.008413
```

and then every thing stops.
In Failure block I put following log 
 NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
Never executed :(

Comment: error message or debug log please!

Comment: No Error message! just stopped uploading!

Comment: The code looks correct, check your server error logs. There could be something going on on your back end server(s)

Comment: see edited description and logs